# interactive Google Translation on android

Tags: android, google-translate

I have an android app: plain text, and I want to make it interactive:
on clicking the word, I want a window to pop up and show the translation of the word

Probably i should use some sort of Google Translate API

please tell me, what direction should i head digging in order to develop such an app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Google Translate you should look into the [Google Translate Api](https://developers.google.com/translate/) docs on developers.google.com.

It isn't free though, Google Translate is a paid service that costs $20 per 1 million characters.

You can use [Google Translate for free](http://rupeshpatel.wordpress.com/2012/06/23/usage-of-google-translator-api-for-free/) but that is stealing and would be unadvisable, especially if you want to publish your app on the Play marketplace.

Microsoft offer a free [Bing Translation Api](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/1899a118-d202-492c-aa16-ba21c33c06cb#schema). It's free up to 2 million characters per month. If you combine that with a caching system so you don't constantly hit it for words already translated then it should work fine.